# Restrict values within XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD which I'm trying to add some restictions to. I want to limit the entries on GroupType to only allow the words "peer" and "child". I've tried the restiction clause in a number of areas but not got it working as yet.

Also some elements removed for brevity but flow has not been changed.

Any help appreciated.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AllMeta">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WikiMeta">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Groups">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WikiGroup">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="GroupType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to limit the entries on GroupType to only allow the words "peer" and "child"

So rather than `type="xs:string"` you will need to give the element a custom `simpleType` with enumerated values:

```
<xs:element name="GroupType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="peer" />
      <xs:enumeration value="child" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

If you need the same restriction elsewhere then you could declare a top-level named `simpleType` and then reference that type by name in the `xs:element`.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I was trying to do this with a top-level simpleType, however I'm more than happy where it is because it only appears once in the schema.